# How do I open sub menu on click on span?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Here are the two scripts I am using

First one adds arrow after `.a` that has `sub-menu`, `.has children`

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('a + ul').prev('a').append('<span class="sub-menu-open">&#9660</span>');
});
```

This second opens `sub-menu`, but on menu a click.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.sub-menu').hide(); //Hide children by default
  $('.menu').children('').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');     
  });
});
```

this is html code.

```
<ul id="menu-izb" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item" class="bp-menu ">
    <a href="/">Activity</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item" class="bp-menu">
    <a href="/">Log Out</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item"><a href="/">Blog
    <span class="sub-menu-open">▼</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="">
    ...
```

How do I make sub-menu toggles onclick on `<span class="sub-menu-open">▼</span>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your JS-Code is doing. But here is a solution for "opening sub menu on click on span":

```
<ul id="menu-izb" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item" class="bp-menu ">
    <a href="/">Activity</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item" class="bp-menu">
    <a href="/">Log Out</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item has-children"><a href="">Blog
  <span class="sub-menu-open">▼</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="">
      <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item">
         Bla1
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item">
         Bla2
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item">
         Bla3
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>




 <script>
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.sub-menu').hide(); 
  $('.sub-menu-open').parent().click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is a working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ehg49dso/9/

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatelly span in my case is inside <a><span></span></a>, and I am looking for solution that span should ignore a link, and do what is in your jsfiddle.

Comment: ah ok, but it doesn't make any sense. If you don't need the link, then just remove the surrounding anchor tag. Why can't you do this?

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer and the fiddle. Now it works with the anchor tag.